# Matplotlib still not installing on v3.8.6 of python. (Earlier I was on v3.9)

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, installation

I was told the wheels for matplotlib are not available for python v3.9 yet so I should try installing v3.8.6. So I uninstalled python and reinstalled it to that version,
But when I ran

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

the output was:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/28/91f26bd088ce8e22169032100d4260614fc3da435025ff389ef1d396a433/pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=51f1c7514530bd5c145d8f13ed936ad6b8bfcb8cf74e10403d0890bc986f0033
Best match: pip 20.2.4
Processing pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Adding pip 20.2.4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.8 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

so I thought pip was install and then I ran:

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

and got this output:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-2.2.5-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 12.9 MB 5.2 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (2.0.1)
Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache
  Downloading backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (2013.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (1.12.0)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 227 kB 17.3 MB/s 
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.7.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (1.8.0rc1)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (115 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 115 kB 19.0 MB/s 
Collecting subprocess32
  Downloading subprocess32-3.5.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (34 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (41.0.1)
Installing collected packages: backports.functools-lru-cache, python-dateutil, cycler, kiwisolver, subprocess32, matplotlib
Successfully installed backports.functools-lru-cache-1.6.1 cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-2.2.5 python-dateutil-2.8.1 subprocess32-3.5.4
```

so I assumed matplotlib was successfully installed and ran this test code in IDLE:

```
#Importing pyplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Plotting to our canvas
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,1])

#Showing what we plotted
plt.show()
```

to which again I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jai/Desktop/Python Programs/Test 1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

can someone please help? I'm on MacOS 10.15.7
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you've installed matplotlib for Python 2, instead of Python 3. Why not use `pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib`?

Comment: Oh I just ran that code and it was finally executed. Worked like a charm, thank you so much!